# I'm unable to get KEY : VALUE after paring a message string

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing

After parsing ( jQuery ) I have the following in console.log

```
[[{"senttime":"Sun, 24 Jul 2016 16:43:59 GMT","signal":"sell","signalmessage":"SELL"}],"14693786401252020","14693786401252020"]
```

I need to retrieve the KEY's senttime, signal and signalmessage with corresponding values ::: Any assistance would be appreciated :::

Comment: Well, once it is parsed, you can access an Array value by using `myArray[index]`. And to access an Object property, you can use `myObject['myKey']` (bracket notation) or `myObject.myKey` (dot notation). You just need to apply this to your Array, what's bothering you here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data[0][0].senttime` , `data[0][0].signal` , `data[0][0].signalmessage`

Working Example to retrieve `senttime` :

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "senttime": "Sun, 24 Jul 2016 16:43:59 GMT",
    "signal": "sell",
    "signalmessage": "SELL"
  }], "14693786401252020", "14693786401252020"
];
var mytime = data[0][0].senttime;
console.log(mytime);
```